# HIbernate doesn't create table that already exist in another database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a bean entity named `com.test.Student` which is mapped to a table named "student" in attendance database using xml. The "student" table in attendance database does not yet exist.

Hibernate is not creating the "student" table on attendance database on application start, even though the property `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto` is set to "update". It is also not generating any exception, warning or query. It simply does not do anything.

After some testing, I came to realize that a student table already exists in some other database named "sms". If I map the `com.test.Student` @Entity to another table name (that does not exist in any database), Hibernate will create it just fine with this config.

Why is Hibernate not creating the "student" table on the mapped database? Is the existance of another table with the same name in another database interfering in some way?

Some info:

- Hibernate ver: 4.3.9
- Spring ver: 4.3.9
- MySQL as DB
- Java 8
- Netbeans asIDE

Comment: set - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to "create-drop"

Comment: Can you post the hibernate exception, or it just does not do anything?

Comment: Look for capitalized version of `student` table, use `SHOW TABLES` query.

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar if I set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to "create-drop" then my data will be lost once I close the application which I don't want

Comment: @GabrielPimenta it doesnot show any exception, and yes it does nothing

Comment: as student table already exists in some other database so hibernate doesnot create it for me
whenever I give a table name which doesnot exist in any of the available databases, then hibernates creates .

Comment: I have edited your question, trying to make it clearer. If no one answers, I will try to take a look at it when I come home.

Comment: @GabrielPimenta thank you for editing, it looks nice now
This is what I mean to say

Comment: @hrishav do you mind posting a picture of your mysql instance, showing all schemas and tables, some code sample of the entity you are trying to persist, and your application.properties file? I will try to reproduce the behavior you are getting

Comment: @GabrielPimenta the schemas with available table names are in the link 
[https://github.com/thejavaprogrammerhrishav/hibernate/blob/master/output1.sql]

and the entity mapping xml is in the link
[https://github.com/thejavaprogrammerhrishav/hibernate/blob/master/student.hbm.xml]

if you see the schemas with table names here you will see that more than two user table already existed in different schemas for which hibernate is not creating table, but when I name the table (in xml) as "student007" then hibernate creates the table as there is no such table in any of the schemas

Comment: @GabrielPimenta what I found is that if the table already exists in any database then hibernate will not create it if required but if the table doesnot exist in any database then hibernate will surely create it

The biggest question is why hibernate is behaving like that?

Comment: Sorry the corrected links are
[link](https://github.com/thejavaprogrammerhrishav/hibernate/blob/master/output1.sql) == for schemas and tables list

[link](https://github.com/thejavaprogrammerhrishav/hibernate/blob/master/student.hbm.xml)== for entity mapping file

Comment: Your scenario is kinda difficult to replicate... On your entity class, did you try specifying the database schema on a @Table annotation? It would be something like `@Table(name = "attendance.student")`

Comment: thanks @GabrielPimenta it really worked for me when I mentioned `attendance.student` instead of only `student`

But It is not clear to me why it doesn't work when I say `table_name=student` although database name is already mentioned in my connectionurl

Comment: Added an answer for completeness. Please consider marking it as correct answer so that people with the same issue know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments section, if hibernate is not creating tables on ddl auto due to table name conflicts between schemas, you should explicitly declare:

```
@Table(name="attendance.student")
```

That way hibernate will create the table correcly. If no schema is explicitly declared there, it will look for other tables with the same name publicly, and therefore, wont create the new one.

Take a look at [this bug description](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile%3ForiginPath%3D%252Fbrowse%252FHHH-12215%23prompt%3FredirectUri%3D%252Fbrowse%252FHHH-12215&ved=2ahUKEwjLlYul6aPjAhUbDrkGHQORBd4QFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2P4ey2NX6foEJR_W7TV46T&cshid=1562537670283). If you want to know more details about how hibernate behaves when creating new tables, you should definately create another post with a more concise scenario, so that we can discuss it further.

Comment: This is working for simple tables, but when I added same solution to joined-subclass in xml configuration its not working. Is there any other configuration I am missing ? Please suggest, any help would be appreciated.